# Database Schema in Zend Framework 2

Tags: mysql, version-control, zend-framework2, database-schema

I am new in zend framework 2. I am alwasys wondering that how to maintain database schema in my web application. suppose i had a website and later on i decided to add new features in my website and it need 5 more tables in an existing database.

Problem:

**How can i create database tables in mysql if they are not exist, if not exist then create new tables before new feature are initiated in zend framework 2?.** By doing this I also maintane my application version control.

Example:
As we did in in wordpress. When we install a new plugin we check first that database has tables for plugin work, if not then we create database first.

Please share with me, what are the **Best Practices** to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1):

First to do that you need a migration tool like [phinx](http://phinx.org/), it will allow you to build migration script and of course rollback script. Moreover you can version your migration scripts, and you can manage different detabase environment and migrating or rollbacking them one by one.

Phinx is easy to use, light and not framework dependent, I don't think it is the best tool ever but it does its duty.

But it works in command line (could be used in ZF2, there are modules, or you using exec command)

Comment: i am confusing. some people say doctrine is best for database migration, what you say? I never used this technique in my application before, so i dont known how it works, please recommend me any good book so i learn how to manage db in my application overtime passes

Comment: I do not know dotrine having its own migration tool, but you can version the schema file, and update database schema with it in CLI. I prefer phinx because I do not use doctrine (too heavy for my usage) I have my own lightweight orm. Doctrine can not natively look for a directory containing all migration script timestamped and can migrate and rollback to a specific timestamp (execute all migration file from current state to desired state)

Comment: Doctrine is good really good indeed as orm, odm and dbal. To me, doctrine does not have to do migration. Because migration is a pain, I do not want something too complicated to use, to understand perfectly what I'm doing, and what the migration tool is doing.
BTW, I don't know any book on that subject, there's so may way to do migration. I use my own experience and feedback.

Comment: Finally, this is what I have been looking for. Phinx is easy to install, great documentation and framework independant... just perfect